# Cascade select when editing a records and the selected values are known

Tags: reactjs

I built a React cascading select component that uses fetch to populate the select options.  This component is part of a server rendered page, not an SPA.  The cascading selects works fine when creating a new record, but editing a record is a different story.

Is there a known pattern or approach I can use when the selected values are known during run time?  For example, when the user clicks a link to open an edit modal.  I hacked together an approach that causes the React component to execute a change event, so I can populate the child select and set its value.  The code smells, and I'm thinking there must be a better approach.